# Apply style with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css

I'm working on web application with asp.net c#, I have a div element, at the server side I apply this style to the div element:

```
spanNivelRiesgo1.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none; visibility:hidden");
```

I have a radiobutton list, on the click event I'm trying to show the div element, but its not working

```
var spanNivelRiesgo = $("spanNivelRiesgo1").is(":visible") ? $("spanNivelRiesgo1") : $("spanNivelRiesgo2");
```

if option no is clicked div has to appear:

```
$(spanNivelRiesgo).css({'display':'block', 'visibility':'visible'});
```

but its not working, I'm really new with jquery, so I'm not sure what is wrong.

Here is the complete code:

```
<div class="span" id="spanNivelRiesgo1" runat="server" visible="False">
                <table class="table_span">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 230px;">Nivel de Riesgo:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNivelRiesgo1" runat="server" Width="150px" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="a"></asp:DropDownList></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

<div class="span" id="spanNivelRiesgo2" runat="server" visible="False">
                <table class="table_span">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 230px;">Nivel de Riesgo:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNivelRiesgo2" runat="server" Width="150px" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="a"></asp:DropDownList></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

On server side:

```
if (_oportunidadMejora)
            {
                rblOportunidadMejora1.Items[0].Selected = rblOportunidadMejora2.Items[0].Selected = true;
                spanNivelRiesgo1.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none; visibility:hidden");
                spanNivelRiesgo2.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none; visibility:hidden");
            }
            else
            {
                rblOportunidadMejora1.Items[1].Selected = rblOportunidadMejora2.Items[1].Selected = true;
                try
                {
                    spanNivelRiesgo1.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block; visibility:visible");
                    ddlNivelRiesgo1.SelectedValue = _nivelRiesgo;
                    spanNivelRiesgo2.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block; visibility:visible");
                    ddlNivelRiesgo2.SelectedValue = _nivelRiesgo;
                }
                catch { }
```

On pageload:

```
rblOportunidadMejora2.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("javascript:return OportunidadMejora();"));
```

client side:

```
function OportunidadMejora(){

            var RB1 = document.getElementById("<%=rblOportunidadMejora2.ClientID%>");
            var spanNivelRiesgo = $("spanNivelRiesgo1").is(":visible") ? $("spanNivelRiesgo1") : $("spanNivelRiesgo2");
            var lblFecha = document.getElementById("<%=lblFechaCumplimiento.ClientID%>");
            var lblPlazo = document.getElementById("<%=lblPlazo.ClientID%>");

            var radio = RB1.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var isChecked = false;

            for (var i = 0; i<radio.length;i++){
                if(radio[i].checked){
                    if(radio[i].value == "True"){//La opción si, está marcada
                        $(spanNivelRiesgo).css({'display':'none', 'visibility':'hidden'});
                        //spanNivelRiesgo.hide();
                        lblFecha.innerHTML = "Fecha de Seguimiento:";
                        lblPlazo.innerHTML = "Plazo de Seguimiento:";
                    }
                    else{//La opción no fue marcada
                        $(spanNivelRiesgo).css({'display':'block', 'visibility':'visible'});
                        //spanNivelRiesgo.show();
                        lblFecha.innerHTML = "Fecha de Cumplimiento:";
                        lblPlazo.innerHTML = "Plazo de Cumplimiento:";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: if spanNivelRiesgo1 is the id of the dropdown, use $('#spanNivelRiesgo1') and if it is a class then use $('.spanNivelRiesgo1')

Comment: Maybe `$("spanNivelRiesgo1")` should be `$("span.NivelRiesgo1")`. Please show your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what was happening with my code, but I decided to use pure JavaScript instead Jquery.

Here is the JS function code:

`var spanNivelRiesgo = document.getElementById('<%=(spanNivelRiesgo1.Visible)?spanNivelRiesgo1.ClientID:spanNivelRiesgo2.ClientID%>')`;

```
if(radio[i].value == "True"){//La opción si, está marcada
                        spanNivelRiesgo.style.display = "none";
                        spanNivelRiesgo.style.visibility = "hidden";
                        lblFecha.innerHTML = "Fecha de Seguimiento:";
                        lblPlazo.innerHTML = "Plazo de Seguimiento:";
                    }
                    else{//La opción no fue marcada
                        spanNivelRiesgo.style.display = "block";
                        spanNivelRiesgo.style.visibility = "visible";
                        lblFecha.innerHTML = "Fecha de Cumplimiento:";
                        lblPlazo.innerHTML = "Plazo de Cumplimiento:";
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `id` (`#`) selector. Then change:

```
var spanNivelRiesgo = $("spanNivelRiesgo1").is(":visible") ? $("spanNivelRiesgo1") : $("spanNivelRiesgo2");
```

To:

```
var spanNivelRiesgo = $("#spanNivelRiesgo1").is(":visible") ? $("#spanNivelRiesgo1") : $("#spanNivelRiesgo2");
```

Also you don't need to wrap `spanNivelRiesgo` beacause it's already a jQuery object. So you can use:

```
spanNivelRiesgo.css({'display':'block', 'visibility':'visible'});
```

Instead:

```
$(spanNivelRiesgo).css({'display':'block', 'visibility':'visible'});
```

Comment: I've changed to this way: var spanNivelRiesgo = $("#spanNivelRiesgo1").is(":visible") ? $("#spanNivelRiesgo1") : $("#spanNivelRiesgo2"); and spanNivelRiesgo.css({'display':'block'})
                        spanNivelRiesgo.css({'visibility':'visible'}); but it's not working yet

Comment: I don't know what you want to do exactly, but [here](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/Ly7k6t65/) you have an example. If you want to show `Nivel de Riesgo1` remove the CSS in the example. Also I change `'visibility':'visible'` to `'opacity':'0.5'`, so you can see what is happening. Let me know if you are understanding now ;)

Comment: In jsfiddle is working, but in my code does not, I dont know if the problem is because that functionality is inside a for statement